# Open native twitter app with hash tag search

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter, nsurl, hashtag

On iOS 5, I'm trying to open a native twitter app with a dynamic hashtag search term.

I've tried:

```
- (void)openForHashTag:(NSString *)hashTag {
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

NSURL *twitterURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"twitter://search?q=%@", hashTag]];
DLog(@"Hashtag URL: %@ ", twitterURL);

if ([app canOpenURL:twitterURL]) {
    [app openURL:twitterURL];
}
else {
    NSURL *safariURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mobile.twitter.com/search?q=%@", hashTag]];
    [app openURL:safariURL];
}
```

}

It seems to go to the hashtag search page, but spends forever loading... Is `twitter://search?q=%@` the wrong format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a lot of head scratching, I realised that the search query for a hash tag should not contain an actual hash tag... Therefore by adding the line

```
 NSString *cleanString = [hashTag stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
```

it now works fine... Mystery solved.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)openForHashTag:(NSString *)hashTag {
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    // NOTE: you must percent escape the query (# becomes %23)
    NSString *cleanQuery = [hashTag stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *twitterURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"twitter://search?query=%@", cleanQuery]];
    if ([app canOpenURL:twitterURL]) {
        [app openURL:twitterURL];
    } else {
        NSURL *safariURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mobile.twitter.com/search?q=%@", cleanQuery]];
        [app openURL:safariURL];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper URL for opening the Twitter app and searching for a hashtag is

```
twitter://search?query=hashtag
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 3.0+

Updating swift version of above code

```
       private func openTwitterHashTag() {

           // self.viewModel.programInfo.twitterHash = "#tag"
    
            guard let hashTagQuery = self.viewModel.programInfo.twitterHash.addingPercentEncoding(
                withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed
            ) else { return }
            
            // CASE: OPEN IN NATIVE TWITTER APP
            if let twitterUrl = URL(string: "twitter://search?query=\(hashTagQuery)"),
                UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(twitterUrl) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(twitterUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                return
            }
            
            // CASE: OPEN ON SAFARI VIEW CONTROLLER
            if let twitterWebUrl = URL(string: "http://mobile.twitter.com/search?q=\(hashTagQuery)") {
                let svc = SFSafariViewController.init(url: twitterWebUrl)
                self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Also Add permission in **info.plist**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>twitter</string>
</array>
```